# hamburger menu + paralax

Tags: html, css

I have a strange combination - parallax and hamburger menu. The problem is m 
  that navigation is dropping down whenever place you will hover, not only 
  when you hover over the hamburger menu icon. I think it is a thick bug in 
  the code, but I cannot find it. I don't have jquery for that. Also, I 
  couldn't find any paralax + hamburger menu tutorial. I am trying to do 
  navigation responsive.

```
HTML 

<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="#" style="font-size: 40px; font-family:'Forte'; color: white; 
padding: 10px 30px; text-decoration:none; ">Vowel</a>
    <a href="#" style="float: right; padding: 10px 10px;">
    <img src="icon_menu.png"></img>
    </a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="about_us.html">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Subscribe</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

CSS

nav {
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background-color: red;
position: fixed;
z-index: 100;
}

#menu-icon {
background-image: url("icon_menu.png");
display: hidden;
width: 32px;
height: 32px;
}

nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
position: fixed;
padding: 20px;
background: red;
width: 100%;
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
display: none; 
}

nav:active ul {
list-style-type: none;
display: none;
position: fixed;
padding: 20px;
background: red;
right: 0px;
top: 60px;
width: 100%;
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
border: 1px solid white;
}

nav:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

nav li {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}


container {
max-width: 960px;
height: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: #f9f9f9;
padding: 25px;
border-top: 1px solid black;
overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is your hover element getting full width. So hover action should be target only to hamburger menu icon.

So add class to that anchor tag on menu icon and using that class you can trigger the hover action.

```
<a class="hamberger-menu" href="#" style="float: right; padding: 10px 10px;">
    <img src="icon_menu.png"></img>
</a>
```

Also need to change your CSS code according it.

```
.hamberger-menu:hover~ul {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't really work. Do you think, it might be a different solution?